# Problems with reading a text-file and putting the tokens into a 2D matrix

Tags: c++, string, vector, matrix, text-files

I have a problem reading a text file and putting in the tokens from the text file into a 2-D matrix.

Here are my codes:

```
   std::vector< vector <std::string> > my_matrix(10, vector <std::string>(10));

ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("class_data.txt", ios_base::in);
char output[100];
if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
    if (!myReadFile.eof()) {
        myReadFile >> output;

        char* token = NULL;
        char* context = NULL;
        char delims[] = " ,\t\n";

        token = strtok_s(output, delims, &context);

        if (token != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    my_matrix[i][j] = *token;
                    cout << "token = " << token << endl;
                    cout << "matrix = " << my_matrix[i][j] << endl;
                    token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

std::cout.width(3); std::cout << left << "ID";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Project1";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Project2";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Project3";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Project4";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Project5";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Project6";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Project7";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Midterm";
std::cout.width(9); std::cout << left << "Final" << std::endl;
std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout.width(10); std::cout << my_matrix[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
}
```

I have no errors, it compiles, but further in the program when I would like to display the 2-D matrix, it does not display it. It holds no value in to whole matrix.

Can anyone help me out and tell me what is the problem ? Is it with the way I did the 2 for loops or is it the way I read the text file ? If problem is found, could anyone suggest a solution.

P.S Sorry if I do not have the best professional codes, but I am a beginner in C++ and I did not take any University level programming courses.

Comment: Could you perhaps show what the input data looks like?

Comment: classdata.txt contains this text : A00529154 76 79 85 91 75 80 90 56 58
A00656624 79 85 0  86 86 76 51 89 92
A02507691 47 94 92 49 77 72 25 25 95
A00612352 41 82 90 58 87  0 50 98 80
A04012435 91 50 78 68 70 60 42 74 85
A00654400 47 94 89 75 80 76  0 71 83
A00577109 44 88 84 86 89 88 99 100 90
A00580920 41 82 80 90 89 97 93 84 86
A04028610 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  
A04063494 90 90 90 90 70 90 90 90 90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a 10x10 matrix and strtok returns a char * to the current token, just pass it to the std::string operator= in the matrix like this:

```
my_matrix[i][j] = token;
```

You also need to rethink the logic in your loop. After the strtok call in the inner for, add a check for the return value and break from both loops if it is NULL. Replace the while loop with an if test.

Edit:

I see you changed the while to a if, However, the 2 for loops need a little change too. I suggest something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && token; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 10 && token; j++) {
       my_matrix[i][j] = token;   // NOTE: not *token here
       cout << "token = " << token << endl;
       cout << "matrix = " << my_matrix[i][j] << endl;
       token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);
   }
}
```

This change also makes the if test before the loops unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it later on today and I will get back at you in a few hours

Comment: Hi @DNT. You helped me before, could you help me again, I have a different kind of issue this time. Could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233993/how-to-declare-a-font-variable-properly or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189706/how-to-use-font-as-a-variable please, and could you tell me how to do it properly ?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a CLR question and my expertise there is minimal :)